# Append code to overwrite a PDF if a file of the same name already exists in the Google Drive folder

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have this script to save my spreadsheet in the Google Drive `Squads` folder..

The name of the saved file is according to the value that is in cell `H2` of the `Gerais` page, sometimes the name repeats and when saving, a new file is created instead of subscribing to the existing one, I would like to add in this code the option that if a file with the same name as this new one already exists, instead of having two files with the same name in the Google Drive `Squads` folder, the old one will disappear completely and only make the new file available

```
    //Create PDF
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/' + // Best to place the line break after '+'
      'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' +  // SHEET ID
        '/export?format=pdf' +
          '&size=0' +
            '&portrait=true' +
              '&fitw=true' + 
                '&top_margin=0' +            
                  '&bottom_margin=0' +         
                    '&left_margin=0' +        
                      '&right_margin=0' +     
                        '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' +
                          '&pagenum=false' +
                            '&gridlines=false' +
                              '&fzr=FALSE' +
                                '&gid=' +
                                  'XXXXXXXXXXXX'; //SHEET PAGE ID

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
    var pdfBlob = docurl.getBlob();

    // Get filename from sheet "Gerais", cell "H2"
    var fileName = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Gerais").getRange("H2").getValue();

    // Create file from blob and name it
    // The newFile is placed in the root folder by default
    var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName);  

    // if folder exists use next 
    if (DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Squads").hasNext()){
      var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Squads").next();

      // if folder does not exist
    } else {
      var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("Squads");// new folder created in the root folder by default
    }

    folder.addFile(newFile); // add new file to folder
    DriveApp.removeFile(newFile); // remove file from root folder
```

I tried to create an interaction between `IF` and `ELSE` too to make the file name match the same as I did for the folder name but I was unsuccessful in trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Overwriting existing `File` in a `Folder` by its name (presumably unique).

**Solution**

How about checking if a file with the name written into `fileName` variable exists and if so, removing it before adding the newly created one? **Modification** will look something like this (your script has be authorized with one the [scopes required for the API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete#auth)):

```
//prepare new file and Squads folder;

var existing = folder.getFilesByName(fileName); //returns file iterator;
var hasFile = existing.hasNext(); //check if iterator isn't empty;
if(hasFile) {
  var duplicate = existing.next(); //access file;

  //delete file;
  var durl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+duplicate.getId();
  var dres = UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl,{
    method: 'delete',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
  });
  if(dres.getResponseCode()>=400) {
    //handle errors;
  }
}

//continue: add file, remove from root, etc;
```

**Notes**

1. The way you define query parameters is the common case of a [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)). Besides, each parameter is hardcoded, which makes the export inflexible. To avoid this, use objects to configure them (as query is nothing more than a set of key-value pairs):

   ```
   var params = {
     format: 'pdf',
     size: 0,
     portrait: true,
     fitw: true,
     top_margin: 0,        
     bottom_margin: 0,        
     left_margin: 0,    
     right_margin: 0,   
     sheetnames: false,
     printtitle: false,
     pagenum: false,
     gridlines: false,
     fzr: 'FALSE',
     gid: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
   };

   //append params to the url;
   var theurl = 'base?'+Object.keys(params).map(function(key){
     return key+'='+params[key];
   }).join('&');
   ```

**Updates**

Corrected `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` call as `method` should be a parameters object property and not an argument.

**Reference**

1. Drive API `delete` [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete);

Comment: Small update - added logic for appending params to a base url

Comment: In order for me to authorize this scoping interaction, can I authorize through GAS via Resources → Google Advanced Services → Drive API V2? Would it be an alternative or has nothing to do with it? Could you help me with this question please? Thanks

Comment: Frederico - I think you could use the advanced service instead, yes, as this is simply a google apps script wrapper for the public API (`remove()` method should suffice)