# Overwriting existing File in a Folder by its name (Part 2)

Tags: google-apps-script

When testing the script this way, when there is no file in the `SQUADS` folder with the name I want to save, it actually saves in the SQUADS folder.

However, when there is a file with the name I want, it saves the new PDF in the main Google Drive folder, the correct would be to delete the existing one in the `SQUADS` folder and save in the `SQUADS` folder

Something is missing and I still don't understand how I can solve

```
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
    var pdfBlob = docurl.getBlob();

    // Get filename from sheet "Work", cell "B5"
    var fileName = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Gerais").getRange("H2").getValue();

    // Create file from blob and name it
    // The newFile is placed in the root folder by default
    var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName);  

    // if folder exists use next 
    if (DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Squads").hasNext()){
      var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Squads").next();

      // if folder does not exist
    } else {
      var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("Squads");// new folder created in the root folder by default
    }

    //prepare new file and Squads folder;

    var existing = folder.getFilesByName(fileName); //returns file iterator;
    var hasFile = existing.hasNext(); //check if iterator isn't empty;
    if(hasFile) {
      var duplicate = existing.next(); //access file;

      //delete file;
      var durl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+duplicate.getId();
      var dres = UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl,'delete',{
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
      });
      if(dres.getResponseCode()>=400) {
        //handle errors;
      }
    }

    //continue: add file, remove from root, etc;

    folder.addFile(newFile); // add new file to folder
    DriveApp.removeFile(newFile); // remove file from root folder
```

Already authorized as seems necessary in Resources → Google Advanced Services → Drive API V2

Comment: Frederico, you could create the file directly in the folder after the `hasFile` check by utilizing the [`createFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(String,String,String)) method on the folder itself (you will have to convert `Blob` to a string, though, as the method accepts content string)
Btw, small note I forgot the last time - don't redefine variables such as `folder`: move its declaration to the function level, set it conditionally, then make the `hasFile` check and after that - create the file

Comment: Another note is that if you are using the advanced service, you don't need to call the public API, after accessing `duplicate` file, you can call it via `{service name that you set}.Files.remove(duplicate.getId())`

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want, if you want to replace the PDF file without changing the file ID, you can also use the method of [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update).

Comment: I will be very honest with you, I tried to adjust in several ways but my weakness in programming ended up totally destroying the possibility of success ... I tried to edit the script in various ways but in all the result was still flawed. @Tanaike I'd like to have the script parse if there is a file in my Google Drive's SQUADS folder with the name I want to save the new file, if it exists, so that it deletes the old one and saves the new one. As if overwriting the old file. If it does not exist, it simply saves.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that you want to change the file ID for replacing the file. In this case, it is required to completely delete the existing file and create new file. By the way, I thought that an error might occur at this script of `var dres = UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl,'delete',{muteHttpExceptions: true, headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}});`. How about this?

Comment: @Frederico Mattos, @Tanaike - my bad, yes (as fetch part was in my answer to part 1), its should be: `UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl,{method:'delete',headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token},muteHttpExceptions:true});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

Removing duplicate file and creating a new one in a target folder.

**Solution**

To expand on part 1 and comments, you could use the `createFile()` method on the target folder to ensure the new file is created directly in it and not in the Drive's root. The resulting modification of your script should look like this:

This sample assumes you named the advanced service `DriveAPI` when activating it. Also note that the `folder` declaration is moved to function scope to behave properly (don't declare variables in a smaller scope [in your case in an `if...else` statement] if you are going to use them in a wider one):

```
//...get token and Blob (do not create the file);

var fileName = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Gerais").getRange("H2").getValue();

//Access or create the 'Squads' folder;
var folder; //declare folder;
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Squads"); //returns iterator;
if(folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
}else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder("Squads");
}

//Remove duplicate file with the same name;
var existing = folder.getFilesByName(fileName); //returns iterator;
if(existing.hasNext()) {
  var duplicate = existing.next();

  //use either Drive API or Advanced service solution here;
}

//add file;
folder.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName);
```

*Advanced Drive service solution*

```
DriveAPI.Files.remove(duplicate.getId());
```

*Drive API solution*

```
var durl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+duplicate.getId();
var dres = UrlFetchApp.fetch(durl,{
  method: 'delete',
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token}
});
if(dres.getResponseCode()>=400) {
  //handle errors;
}
```

**Reference**

1. `createFile()` from Blob [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(BlobSource)) [`Folder` class];
2. `Drive` advanced service [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive);
3. `Files` resource [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) [Drive public API];
4. [Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58149406/11407695) (see parameters handling);

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and the time you used to clear up my remaining questions. The system was perfect and even faster than before, thank you very much!

Comment: @FredericoMattos - no problem, glad to help!

Comment: Nice work @OlegValter! You can look at Google Batch API for more productive also.

Comment: @contributorpw -thank you! Agreed, will expand further later (batching ops was out of scope of the OP's question, but since we are here :)